# How to quantify if one animal is following another

Tags: r, modeling, conditional-probability, biostatistics, ecology

I have information on the order of arrivals of 2 species to food. But I want to find out if species 2 is following species 1. In some cases one of, or neither species will arrive to the food. Would a conditional probability work in this case? I'm working in R and here's an example of what I'm thinking it would look like:

```
species1 <- c(0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1)
species2 <- c(1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0)
```

So species 1 arrives 6/13 times and species 2 arrives 3/13 times. Species 2 arrives after species 1 2/13 times.
Firstly, is this a sensible way to quantify what I'm after? If so, how do I achieve this in R?

Comment: Yes, you can calculate conditional probability from this data -- what do you mean by asking if it is going to "work"?

Comment: @Tim I've haven't come across anyone doing this sort of analysis before in ecology which surprised me.

Comment: Isn't an analysis of this type another expression of ecological dominance, as in predator-prey relationships?

Comment: @DJohnson I don't see how it would apply to predator prey dynamics but maybe ecological succession? I think the time scales involved there are far longer than anything I'd be looking at.